# Restrict access meteor app access to specific IPs

Tags: apache, meteor, reverse-proxy, openshift-origin, ddp

we have an apache reverse proxy in front of our meteor app. there is no firewall between the proxy and meteor so users who can hit the proxy can also hit meteor. i want to restrict meteor app access to ONLY the reverse proxy. the meteor app and the apache proxy are hosted in OSE 3

i thought of 2 main possible solutions.

1) use OSE3/kerbenetes to restrict meteor access to ONLY the apache proxy

2) include a signed http request header value in proxy to meteor request so meteor can verify the request is from the proxy. 
 - could not figure this one out

i prefer option 1 to option 2. how can i leverage services in OSE 3 to accomplish option 1? if option 1 is not possible how can i do option 2? if both are impossible, what alternatives do i have?

Comment: are you saying the proxy and meteor app run on the same machine? if so, bind the meteor app to the localhost only 127.0.0.1 and then the proxy running on the same host will be the only machine able to reach the local meteor service. If you run on different machines, the simplest thing to do is set a firewall rule.

Answer (score 0):

Routing in ose3 exposes a service to the outside world. So if we remove a route then the service is only available internally through its cluster ip. Thus remove any routes associated with the meteor app and only leave a apache proxy route exposed. Then in side the apache httpd.conf proxy using the meteor app's ip address.